# How can I add a transition to the toggle?

Tags: javascript, toggle, sidebar

I use this to toggle the sidebar:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.sbt').click(function () {
    $('.sidebar').toggle();
});
```

});

you can see it work here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Jacob_Sell/Ye7wp/

I think the toggle looks to jumpy at the moment, how can I add a transition to make it look smoother?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sbt').click(function () {
        $('.sidebar').toggle(300);
    });
});
```

[**Updated DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ye7wp/1/)

Comment: The simplicity is awesome. Do you know how I could say make it fade?

Comment: @Jacob take a look at [fadeToggle](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/). Used the same way as toggle

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Praveen16oct90/Ye7wp/4/

```
**$(document).ready(function () {
$('.sbt').click(function () {
    $('.sidebar').toggle(2000);
});
});**
```